# Compress histogram of bytes

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, compression, bit-manipulation

Hi I want to compress a histogram of bytes further. I have an Input array which consists of is  1 until 256 Bytes. From this array I create a histogram, which should as small as possible.

Here is what i have done so far:

```
public byte[] toBitSetHistogram(byte[] in){
  int[] hist = new int[256];

  for(byte b : in){
    hist[b+128]++;
  }

  Bitset set = new BitSet();

  for(int i =0,o=0; i < hist.length; i++){
    o += hist[i];
    set.set(o++);
  }

  return set.toByteArray();
}
```

for an input array of:

256 bytes I need 64 histogram Bytes

1 byte I need 33 histogram Bytes

How can I reduce the size of the histogram further?

Comment: Wait, I get it, you are storing a number of occurences as a number of zero's ending with a `1`. So you are representing a number by counting bits? You think counting is better compressed than a number?

Comment: I guess you are still getting a reasonably good value, but you may want to switch between representations depending on the amount of values. Obviously, sparing a single bit / byte, you should be able to encode a histogram for a single byte using one or two bytes

Comment: Yes I represent the number by count the bits because, I dont know how to compress efficently the potential various sized histogram values.

Comment: I tried an interesting encoding, but it got bigger instead of smaller due to the large amount of small values. Note that your histogram calculation is *not* correct for positive values, replace `b + 128` with `b & 0xFF` (and do use spaces).

Comment: It is correct due to the language is java and a byte can have the values -128 <= b <=127. The array index is int and so +128 has the same bit value like 0xFF.

Comment: Well, kind of. But generally we present the value 0 as, well `0x00` and `128` as `0x80`. As indicated I see little to nothing wrong with your encoding, but obviously for very few bytes you could have smaller encodings (value, frequency pairs would result in 2 bytes for a single byte "histogram"). So just calculate which one is smaller and use that. You can use a single bit to switch between representations (or hardcode it and include the amount of numbers in the encoding). Your current solution is uses a statically sized encoding (other possibly than for some trailing bits), fine as well.